# Installing python package throws error

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to install the Python Mesa Package. (https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/)

I am using PyCharm 5.04 and its default package manager which I understand is pip. I am getting the following error, which I understand is related to it not being able to compile some c++ libraries? I have updated my Visual Studio to the latest 2015 edition, but to no avail.

I am using Windows 8.1 64-bit and my project is using Python 3. Any advice? Logs shown below.

```
DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
Downloading/unpacking Mesa
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\dario_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\Mesa\setup.py) egg_info for package Mesa

Downloading/unpacking tornado (from Mesa)
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\dario_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\tornado\setup.py) egg_info for package tornado

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\build'
    warning: no files found matching 'tornado\test\README'
Downloading/unpacking numpy (from Mesa)
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\dario_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\numpy\setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking pandas (from Mesa)
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\dario_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\pandas\setup.py) egg_info for package pandas
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\setup.py:327: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with "
    C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1640: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1649: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1652: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1542: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1553: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1556: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 149, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 177, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 18, in run
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 147, in run
      File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 158, in build_sources
      File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 293, in build_library_sources
      File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 376, in generate_sources
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 652, in get_mathlib_info
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_link
        self._check_compiler()
      File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 51, in _check_compiler
      File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\msvccompiler.py", line 17, in initialize
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 259, in query_vcvarsall
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1000, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup
        lambda: execfile(
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 100, in run
        return func()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>
        {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 78, in execfile
        exec(compile(source, fn, 'exec'), globs, locs)
      File "setup.py", line 386, in <module>

      File "setup.py", line 378, in setup_package
        lib_depends = []
      File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 166, in setup
        raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
    SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\dario_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\pandas\setup.py", line 604, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 109, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 239, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs
        parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 564, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 802, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 814, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 809, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1015, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1003, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Running from numpy source directory.

C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\setup.py:327: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates

  warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with "

C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1640: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1649: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1652: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'

C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1542: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1553: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1556: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 149, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 177, in run

    self.run_command("egg_info")

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 18, in run

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 147, in run

  File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 158, in build_sources

  File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 293, in build_library_sources

  File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 376, in generate_sources

  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 652, in get_mathlib_info

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_link

    self._check_compiler()

  File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 51, in _check_compiler

  File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\msvccompiler.py", line 17, in initialize

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 259, in query_vcvarsall

    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")

distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1000, in run_setup

    run_setup(setup_script, args)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup

    lambda: execfile(

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 100, in run

    return func()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>

    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 78, in execfile

    exec(compile(source, fn, 'exec'), globs, locs)

  File "setup.py", line 386, in <module>



  File "setup.py", line 378, in setup_package

    lib_depends = []

  File "C:\Users\DARIO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6f6l20jh\numpy-1.11.0\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 166, in setup

    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))

SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\dario_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\pandas\setup.py", line 604, in <module>

    **setuptools_kwargs)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 109, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 239, in __init__

    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs

    parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 564, in resolve

    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 802, in best_match

    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 814, in obtain

    return installer(requirement)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg

    return cmd.easy_install(req)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install

    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item

    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 809, in install_eggs

    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1015, in build_and_install

    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1003, in run_setup

    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\dario_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\pandas
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\dario_000\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: The library being installed is not the same, but the error mentioned in question seems to be a duplicate of the error encountered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: @ilim I tried setting VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS% as suggested in your link but get the same error.